# MS Word mailmerge using Thunderbird

Tags: microsoft-word, thunderbird, mail-merge

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

> Thunderbird does not support mail
>   merge directly.

Source (and more info): [MozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Mail_merge)

Comment: Yes I had seen that. I am trying to still use Word and not Open Office. I have a substantial amount of word templates and am trying to prevent amending them all. At worst I could use Outlook Express or Windows Mail, but if I can avoid that and use Thunderbird then that would be my preference.